# How does Keras read input data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I am using Keras for a project and I don't understand how Keras uses data input, that is to say how Keras reads our input data when creating the first layer.

For example:

1. model = Sequential()
2. model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=3,name='layer1'))

In this model, what does it mean to have 10 neurons and an input with 3 dimensions? If the input data has 100 examples (number of lines in the matrix data), how does Keras use them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input_dim=3` means that your data have 3 features which will be used to determine final result eg. if you want to determine what animal data refer to you could put width, height and color as data.

`100 examples` of different animals widths, heights and colors combinations allow neural network to adjust its parameters (learn) what width, height and color refers to what kind of animal. Keras starts with random weights for neurons and goes one by one 100 times using provided samples to adjust network weights. Keras actually uses batches which means 100 samples are divided into smaller groups for better learning rate and general performance (less data to store in memory at once).

`10 neurons` are 10 'places' where network is able to store multiplications results between neuron weights and input data. You could imagine neuron as a bulb which lights a bit brighter or darker depending whether data shows some useful data feature eg. if animal is above 3 meters tall. Each neuron has its own set of weights which are changed just a bit when network examines next sample from your data. At the end you should have 10 neurons (bulbs) which react in more or less intense way depending on presence of different features in your data eg. if animal is very tall.

The more neurons you have the more possible features you can track eg. if animal is tall, hairy, orange, spotted etc. But the more neurons you have there is also the higher risk that your network will be too exact and will learn features which are unique for your training example (it's called overfitting) but do not help you to recognize animal samples which were not included in your training data (it's called ability to generalize and is most important point of actually training neural network). Selecting number of neurons is then a bit of practical exercise where you search for one which works for your need.

I hope it clarifies your doubts. If you would like to get deeper in this field there are a lot of good resources online explaining neural networks training process in details including features, neurons and learning.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand much better. Thanks :D 
I have another question, if I may. If we use your example with animals. How can I get an output in 3 dimensions with the right values "width", "height" and "color"? I know that values in a neural network are between 0 and 1 so I don't understand how we can get those values ?

Comment: @Jeremy: It depends whether your values are numbers like width/height or if they are labels eg. colors represented with names. If they are labels than you first need to represent them as numbers (could be as simple as 0 for red and 1 for green or more precise like converted to decimals representation of hex colors). Now when all the input is represented by number the term you are looking for is normalization. Normalization is mathematical process which allows you to 'translate' any range of numbers into other range eg. width from range 50 - 250 into range 0 - 1.

Answer (score 3):

`input_dim=3` means each of your input data has 3 dimensions. In your case, your input data with 100 examples should have a shape of `(100,3)`. The number of examples doesn't really matter when you compile your model. But you should make sure the dimension of each of your input data matches the `input_dim` that you set in your first Dense layer.

A short example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adamax')

model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=50, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me to understand better. :)